# L2S : Only specific returns

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have two tables, call them Employee and Contacts.

Contacts has a many-to-one relationship with Employee, on EmployeeID. I'm trying to retrieve all employees who might have a collection of contact values stored against their names, using Linq-to-Sql:

```
var employee = (from e in db.Employees 
where e.Contacts.Select(x => x.EmployeeID == e.ID) 
select e);
```

But this does not work, as `e.Contact.Select(...)` returns `IQueryable<bool>` instead of `bool`.

I've been trying different scenarios, but can find something that's simple and cheap to perform.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> employees who might have a collection
>   of contact values

Did you mean:

```
from e in db.Employees
where e.Contacts.Any()
select e
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var employee = (from e in db.Employees 
where e.Contacts.Any()
select e);
```

This will select all employees who have at least 1 contact record related to it.

Note that the `.Select(x => x.EmployeeID == e.ID)` is redundant as e.Contacts is a collection of only those contacts related by this foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var employee = (from e in db.Employees 
where e.Contacts.Select(x => x.EmployeeID).Contains(e.ID) 
select e);
```